# Does it make sense to apply complicated mathematics to calculate with precision when the margin of error is +/-10%?

Tags: mathematics

This is more of a philosophical question than general question. Quantitative finance applies highly complicated mathematics and has attracted very smart people to this field lately given the high pay banks are willing to pay for such talent. However, in finance, the margin of error is huge because much of finance and investment relates to the future.

Does it make sense to apply complicated mathematics to calculate with precision when the margin of error is +/-10%?

Comment: Is this an [actual problem you face in the course of your work](http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I think it's more appropriate for a meta discussion, and there is lack of a clear question(what particular margin of error is comfortable for a given calculation and how to arrive at it, etc.).  But I'd say it's certainly a problem many of us face in our work.